# eclipse package for android

Tags: android, eclipse, package

I'm a newbie in Android development and I have some difficulties with installing environment. Normally I'm trying to solve this questions by myself, however here I really need your help. This questions may look for you a bit stupid, I'm sorry for this in advance.
First question: is it really matters which eclipse package I will use? I saw it's a number of different packages like Luna, Mars, Neon and so on, and each package has different versions of eclipse, which one I should use?
I installed Eclipse platform(version 3.8.1) on my Ubuntu 15.10, connected ADT plugins, SDK, everything were ok, until I created a new project. It gave me an error "Could not open the editor: The editor class could not be instantiated. This usually indicates a missing no-arg constructor or that the editor's class name was mistyped in plugin.xml." and long list of problems under "Details" button.

Comment: just asking ... is jdk installed ?

Comment: @Mahfa sure! and jre too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

and why you want to use eclipse ?
The official IDE now for android is Android Studio its pretty simple and better here's the link to download it and it's easy to download too :

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: oh, it's the second question I'm interested in!) While surfing the internet I found that people mostly use eclipse and android-studio in symbiosis, but I didn't got the idea for what purpose they need eclipse, I just follow the instructions.

Comment: it's about that google stopped supporting eclipse , because android studio their offical IDE and makes coding more easier than eclipse

Comment: thank you for your answer, I'll try my best with Android studio)